# Google analytics homepage display

Tags: php, google-analytics

I've been looking around for a while now and have yet to find an answer. Does anybody have any insight as to why, when i'm checking numbers, my 'homepage' displays as:

> "/index.php,index/,index,index-,/index.php"

on a single line in GA?

I've seen the same on a few other pages:

> /customer_account-exec/index.php,index/,index,index-,/index.php

Is this possibly a URL rewrite issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics records whatever the URL of the page is. To clean up the multiple versions of a URL (specially the home page), you have to make a number of changes in your **Profile Settings**.

You can follow this [detailed tutorial](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/12/17/cleaning-urls-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1398104394) for cleaning up your URLs in Google Analytics.